# adding points to a weather map

Tags: jquery, dictionary, clickable

I have a weather map on my website (jpg), but it does not indicate cities. I would like to add point (with an index) show particular cities. What is the best way to do that. Can I use jquery for that?

Comment: Depends on how do you plan to find the appropriate coordinates of the cities on your jpg image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="weathermap">
    <a class="point pos1" href="/city_1" title="City One"><span class="hide">City one</span><span class="dot">.</span></a>
    <a class="point pos2" href="/city_2" title="City Two"><span class="hide">City two</span><span class="dot">.</span></a>
    <img src="weather.jpg" alt="Weather Map" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #weathermap {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
    } 

    .point {
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 16px;
    }

    span.hide {
        display: none; // Don't show 'city one' on the map
    }

    span.dot {
        display: block;
        // This background picture is a simple marker of 16px by 16px
        background: transparent url(marker.png) no-repeat scroll center center;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        text-indent: -9999px; //Remove the dot to replace it with a marker
    }

    .pos1 {
        top: 50px;
        left: 100px;
    }

    .pos2 {
        top: 120px;
        left: 10px;
    }
```

To add another city, just add another `<a ...>` to your HTML and give it another classname, like pos3. Then you can add `.pos3` to you CSS-code and change the coordinates with `top` and `left` values